# Finding the Sunday between the 1st and 2nd Tuesday of the month

Tags: powershell

Fairly new to PS, I want to batch file on Sunday between the 1st and the 2nd Tuesday of the month.
I know how to find the the 1st and 2nd Tuesdays I am looking for, cannot figure out the rest.

```
$FindNthDay = 1
$WeekDay = 'Tuesday'
[datetime]$Today = [datetime]::NOW
$todayM = $Today.Month.ToString()
$todayY = $Today.Year.ToString()
[datetime]$StrtMonth1 = $todayM + '/1/' + $todayY
while ($StrtMonth1.DayofWeek -ine $WeekDay ) { $StrtMonth1 = $StrtMonth1.AddDays(1) }
$StrtMonth1.AddDays(7 * ($FindNthDay - 1))
#
$FindNthDay = 2
$WeekDay = 'Tuesday'
[datetime]$Today = [datetime]::NOW
$todayM = $Today.Month.ToString()
$todayY = $Today.Year.ToString()
[datetime]$StrtMonth = $todayM + '/1/' + $todayY
while ($StrtMonth.DayofWeek -ine $WeekDay ) { $StrtMonth = $StrtMonth.AddDays(1) }
$StrtMonth.AddDays(7 * ($FindNthDay - 1))
```

Comment: 1st tuesday otta always be in the `1..7` range, so the 1st sunday after that is what you want.

Comment: The Sunday you want is five days after the first Tuesday.  Can you add five days to the date you find?

Answer (score 0):

> I know how to find the the 1st and 2nd Tuesdays

Since there's only *one* Sunday in between, you only need to find the first one:

```
# Get-Date -Day 1 will give us the 1st of the current month
$firstTuesday = Get-Date -Day 1
while($firstTuesday.DayOfWeek -ne 'Tuesday') {
  $firstTuesday = $firstTuesday.AddDays(1)
}
```

And then add another 5 days:

```
$sundayAfterFirstTuesday = $firstTuesday.AddDays(5).Date
```

Which (in January 2021) gives us:

```
PS ~> $sundayAfterFirstTuesday
Sunday, January 10, 2021 12:00:00 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Mathias's fine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65649867/4749264), I got hung up on this.  Given that `.DayOfWeek` is an `[enum]` that's easily converted to a `[Int]` I was looking for a mathematically concise way to derive the first Tuesday. Since it's fairly obvious how to then find the following Sunday by just doing `.AddDays(5)` .

Honestly, I was stumbling a bit because While `.DayOfWeek` is 0 - 6 how many days to add depends on if the current day, in this case the first of the month, is less than or greater than Tuesday (2).  It was worth playing around; here are 2 alternate approaches I came up with:

Example 1: A switch statement that's not at all concise but is very readable:

```
    $Day1 = Get-Date "1/1/2021"
    Switch ( $Day1.DayOfWeek )
    {
        'Sunday'    { $Sunday = $Day1.Adddays(2).AddDays( 5 ); Break }
        'Monday'    { $Sunday = $Day1.Adddays(1).AddDays( 5 ); Break }
        'Tuesday'   { $Sunday = $Day1.AddDays( 5 );            Break }
        'Wednesday' { $Sunday = $Day1.Adddays(6).AddDays( 5 ); Break }
        'Thursday'  { $Sunday = $Day1.Adddays(5).AddDays( 5 ); Break }
        'Friday'    { $Sunday = $Day1.Adddays(4).AddDays( 5 ); Break }
        'Saturday'  { $Sunday = $Day1.Adddays(3).AddDays( 5 ); Break }
    }
    $Sunday
```

This is also easy to adjust. For example, if you wanted to switch to 1st Sunday between 1st & 2nd Monday etc...

For the mathematical / logic approach it came out a little more crude:

```
    $Day1 = Get-Date "1/1/2021"
    
    If( [Int]$Day1.DayOfWeek -gt 2 ) { $Interval = 7 - ([Int]$Day1.DayOfWeek - 2) }
    Else { $Interval = 2 - [Int]$Day1.DayOfWeek }
    
    $Sunday = $Day1.AddDays( $Interval ).AddDays( 5 )
    $Sunday
```

The above example can be more concise in PowerShell 7+ using the ternary operator:

```
    $Day1     = Get-Date "1/1/2021"
    $Interval = $Day1.DayOfWeek -gt 2 ? 7 - ([Int]$Day1.DayOfWeek - 2) : 2 - [Int]$Day1.DayOfWeek
    $Sunday   = $Day1.AddDays( $Interval ).AddDays( 5 )
    $Sunday
```

Note: all of the examples user 1/1/2021 as the starting date, but I did test across multiple 1st days of the month, For example, if the first day was a Monday, Sunday, Thursday etc...

Note: Some of the `[Int]` casting can probably be removed if one is careful about PowerShell type conversion system, but I wanted to get this out there.  If I have time I'll cleanup further.

Answer (score 0):

Or a slightly different approach:

```
$BaseDate = (Get-Date 3/1/2021)
$BaseDate.AddDays( (& {if ([int]$BaseDate.DayOfWeek -gt 2) {14}
                       else { 7 } }) - [int]($BaseDate).DayOfWeek)
```

Sunday, March 7, 2021 12:00:00 AM